# Can't make Mutation to work using react-apollo-hooks with React Native project

Tags: react-native, react-apollo

I have a React Native project and I would like to make Apollo GraphQL work. I tried everything, I refer the issue I am having which I did the submission here: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at MutationData.onMutationCompleted (react-hooks.cjs.js:654)](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues)

Am I doing something wrong in configuration or usage?
Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: issue has been resolved back in time